# Characterizing relationship between two datasets

Tags: probability, forecasting, prediction

I have two data sets of electricity prices in a given region, one with data at 5 minute intervals and one with just the hourly values (which are almost, but not quite, averages of the 5 minute values within the hour).  The hourly average data set goes back much further in time. I would like to study the variances of the 5-minute data vs. the hourly so I can make estimations or predictions as to the chance of the 5-minute price exceeding a given value if I only have the hourly average.

How would you go about this?  My Stats 101 approach has been to look at the standard deviation of either the ratio or the difference between the 5 minute and hourly data.  But, now I'm realizing that that was assuming a normal distribution for the ratio/differences, which turns out not to be true.

Given a large data set of mappings of 1 hourly value to 12 5-minute values, how can I estimate the chance that any hourly value maps to one or more 5-minute values >= some threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a handle on the variance of the 5 minute data. So I would suggest calculating this variance within each hour. Then plot this variance against the hourly value for this particular hour. You may be able to see a linear or other relationship that may allow you to model the 5 minute variance as a function of the hourly value.

I also assume that there is some seasonality, both yearly (higher electricity consumption in winter) and weekly (different residential/industry patterns between weekdays and weekends).

Conversely, you may want to look into the literature on electricity forecasting, which is an active research field. People there usually work in 5 or 15 minute time increments, and they of course need to model variance in some way. Time series methods may help you quite independently of the hourly data.

Comment: Hi @Stephan, and thanks for replying. It hadn't occurred to me to treat the hourly variance as the data set of interest, I'll give that a try.

In the literature most of the work seems to be about longer time scales--sub-hourly price excursions are treated as unpredictable. One of the first articles included the phrase "usually ill-behaved price series".

In case anyone finds this thread and is working a similar problem, the quick and dirty solution was to realize that you don't need to characterize the variance.  With a large data set, you can determine P(X>n) simply by counting.